# Chance of late deliveries (combining two Poisson processes)

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution

If sent mail is a Poisson distributed process with $\lambda = 100$ and delivery men deliver a number of envelopes per day which also turns out to be Poisson distributed with say $\lambda = 10$, how many delivery men should the post office hire such that at most $5\%$ of mail is expected to be late?

For the sake of the question, assume the delivery men deliver at a rate independent of the amount of mail.

I realise these processes may not actually be Poisson distributed, but this was the best example I could come up with to illustrate the problem of combining these two processes.

Comment: This is very much alike to cascading nuclear decays. The type of question is usually not asked there, but I would write the (differential) equation and solve it. With the formula, it is a "simple" propagation of the distribution characteristics (simple in the sense of straightforward).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am making this to simple, but: Let $S \sim \mathcal{Po}(\lambda=100)$ be the sent mail, and the delivered mail is $D \sim \mathcal{Po}(10 \cdot N)$ where $N$ is the number of mailmen. By independence, the number $N=S-D$ not delivered on time (zero or negative if all delivered) have a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution), there is an implementation in R package `skellam`. Then the $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \P(N \le 0)$ can be calculated directly for various $N$.

But to control that at most 5% is late is more tricky. That $N \le 0.05S$ can be written $0.95S \le D$ and its probability can be calculated by conditioning as 
$$
\P(0.95S \le D) = \sum_{d=0}^\infty \P(S \le d/0.95)\cdot \P(D=d)
$$
which at least can be evaluated numerically.

Comment: This is very nice, I was not familiar with the Skellam distribution!